# Where or how to specify log file in barracuda webserver?

Tags: embedded-linux, embeddedwebserver

I have a realtimelogic's Barracuda application Server hosted on a m68k based embedded linux system.
When i enable https in it, i get exception and it kills the application. I would like to know where the exceptions will be logged in a barracuda webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is Httptrace, and it should be created in the current directory of the server?